# How does telnet give me access to applications behind a firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, telnet

In a work project I'm working on, I'm required to do `telnet <ip address> <port>` before running my application to make sure we can reach connected services. I cannot connect to those other services (eg. cannot hit the API endpoint of another service) until I run that telnet command.

I've searched on what telnet is and it is a network protocol used to connect to remote systems over a TCP/IP network. Does that mean that when I run telnet, I establish a connection between my local workstation and the servers that those application reside on, so that my application is able to connect to those other services through that connection?

I'd appreciate some confirmation or clarification! Thank you.

Comment: What sort of "application" are you talking about? Is it something you run in the terminal, within the telnet session, or something else?

Comment: Something else! After I run the telnet session, the command returns and I can successfully hit the server that I previously couldn't connect to. In this case I was just testing out some APIs on Postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Telnet **on its own** doesn't really give you access to anything except the system that you're telnetting to. A Telnet connection is no different from an SSH or RDP connection – it lets you talk to a remote CLI and that's it. (Though the `telnet` client is also commonly used for any other kind of text-based TCP connection, not always for Telnet as such.)

However, the *remote system* that you're telnetting to is probably configured to run a script that adds the client's IP address to the firewall as soon as you log in (or even as soon as you connect). For example, with a typical Telnet server that takes you to a login shell, it takes just 2-3 lines of shell script in /etc/profile to implement this. (OpenBSD even comes with an elaborate "authpf" system out-of-the-box.)

Alternatively, a *firewall* (either on the system itself or anywhere along the way) might also be configured with a rule that adds your IP address to a list whenever the rule matches a packet. This is often used for "port knocking". For example, in Linux nftables one might have a rule like this:

```
tcp dport 23 update @allowed_clients_v4 { ip saddr }

ip saddr @allowed_clients_v4 accept
```

...which reacts to inbound Telnet connections (port 23) by adding the client to an "allowed IPs" list and automatically giving that client temporary access to all ports.